# Python Regex ? operation: is there a return preference, 0 or 1?

Tags: python

This question is about the operation '?'. In my previous question, someone mistakenly mark my question as a duplicate. SO I reopen this question asking for an answer.

I would like to ask why the first expression doesn't output ('a', 'b','c','d') from the string 'axxxxxbcd'.

```
import re
match = re.findall(r'(a).*?(b)?.*?(c)?(d)','awsssd axxxxxbcd ad adfdfdcdfdd 
awsbdfdfdcd')
print (match)
```

output[1]: [('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', '', 'c', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd')]

```
import re

match = re.findall(r'(a).*?(b)?(c)?(d)','awsssd axxxxxbcd ad adfdfdcdfdd awsbdfdfdcd')
print (match)
```

output[2]: [('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', 'b', '', 'd')]

@Isaac

Comment: you might want to take a look at https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can better understand what is going on by wrapping every element of the regex in capturing parentheses:

```
import re

rgx1 = re.compile(r'(a)(.*?)(b)?(.*?)(c)?(d)')
m1 = rgx1.search('axxxxxbcd')
print(m1.groups())
```

Output:

```
('a', '', None, 'xxxxxb', 'c', 'd')
```

Here's what happens:

```
# Group 1: 'a'
# Group 2: capture as little as possible, so we get ''
# Group 3: 'b' is not present, but it's optional, so we get None
# Group 4: 'xxxxxb'
# Group 5: 'c'
# Group 6: 'd'
```

Why does group 4 end up with content rather than group 2? Initially, they are the same, capturing as little as possible (nothing), but that will cause the overall regex to fail. So the engine has to start expanding either group 2 or group 4. Based on this one example, it appears that the engine expands the latter group first -- but I don't know what the precise implementation rules are for situations like this. To demonstrate that the two groups do indeed pursue a non-greedy strategy, you can add a `d` earlier in the string: for example, use the input text `axxdxxxbcd`. In that case, group 4 ends up holding just `xx`.

The following approach might do what you want:

```
rgx1 = re.compile(r'(a)(?:.*?(b)|.*?)(?:.*?(c)|.*?)(d)')
m1 = rgx1.search('a...b...cd')
print(m1.groups())  # Output: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

But I probably wouldn't solve the problem that way. Regexes where every (or nearly every) element is optional are often tricky to get right. Sometimes you are better off to parse the text in a few simple stages rather than in a big hairy regex.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't know there is a difference between group 2 and group 4.

Comment: @XiaoboLi It's a good question. I added another paragraph to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I do like your regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that output  because of 
.*? matches any character (except for line terminators

```
(a).*?(b)?.*?(c)?(d)

Group 1.    0-1 `a`
Group 3.    7-8 `c`
Group 4.    8-9 `d`
```

**1st Capturing Group (a)**

a matches the character a literally (case sensitive)
.*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

**2nd Capturing Group (b)?**

? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
b matches the character b literally (case sensitive)
.*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
*? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

**3rd Capturing Group (c)?**

? Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
c matches the character c literally (case sensitive)

**4th Capturing Group (d)**
d matches the character d literally (case sensitive)

But if you want output ('a', 'b','c','d') from the string 'axxxxxbcd'

your regular expression should be

```
 (a).*?(b)?(c)?(d)

Group 1.    0-1 `a`
Group 2.    6-7 `b`
Group 3.    7-8 `c`
Group 4.    8-9 `d`
```